# How can I extend and implement two libraries at the same time?

Tags: android

I would like to build an activity that uses the Youtube API, and App compact activity.

How can I merge these two libraries together:

Youtube library:

```
public class Activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener { }
```

App compact activity library

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity { }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Multiple inheritence is not supported by Java (for better or for worse), and `YouTubeBaseActivity` extends `Activity`

Comment: It is not possible in java to extend from two classes

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Why do you need both of them anyway. maybe we can help with that problem

Comment: I would like to create an activity that shows an youtube video at the top, and a pager adapter at the bottom. I need to call a method called "getSupportFragmentManager()", but I can't do it without extending the AppCompatActivity, thats why I was trying to use both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple inheritence is not supported by Java (for better or for worse), and `YouTubeBaseActivity` extends `Activity`, if `YoutubeBaseActivity` extended `AppCompatActivity` you would have had your wish !

In my opinion not supporting multiple inheritence was the right way as it can cause the [diamond problem of multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) among inexperienced developers.
To Quote WikiPidea

> The "diamond problem" (sometimes referred to as the "deadly diamond of
>   death") is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C
>   inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If there is a
>   method in A that B and C have overridden, and D does not override it,
>   then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of
>   C?

As for your problem

> I would like to create an activity that shows an youtube video at the
>   top, and a pager adapter at the bottom. I need to call a method called
>   "getSupportFragmentManager()", but I can't do it without extending the
>   AppCompatActivity, thats why I was trying to use both

Use [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) if you are only playing a YouTube video in a single support.v4.app.Fragment. This allows you to use FragmentActivity, rather than YouTubeBaseActivity.