# How can I attach my YouTubePlayerSupportFragment when I'm in a BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

What I've done in a fragment previously is:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(/* .. */);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fl_youtube, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

This works fine. However now I have a `BaseExpandableListAdapter` that sets up content on expand in `getChildView`. There's no `getChildFragmentManager`. What am I supposed to do now?

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, 
                         int childPosition, 
                         boolean isLastChild, 
                         View convertView, 
                         ViewGroup parent) {
   // How do I add attach the YouTubeFragment?
}
```

Comment: There is also YouTubePlayerView which is much suitable for lists. why you wana use fragment?

Comment: @Selvin It needs me to extend my activity and that puts me into an impossible situation, since we don't have multiple inheritance. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35803319/29347

Comment: If you only needs is to extend from AppCompatActivity  then you may use AppCompatDelegate like [here](https://github.com/SelvinPL/SyncFrameworkAndroid/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/pl/selvin/android/listsyncsample/authenticator/AccountAuthenticatorActivityAppCompat.java)